# Access folder of parent website from mobile website after htaccess redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm redirecting my website to mobile website when access through a mobile device.

Here's the htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^desktop
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android|avantgo|blackberry|iphone [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Folder structure of FTP is like this:

```
Images
ProImages
Mobile // All mobile site data into this
```

When I attempt to access `http://www.example.com/ProImages/abc.jpg` from my mobile website, it doesn't show up because as soon as it tries to call `www`, it redirects to `m`.

I tried using `../ProImages` but that again didn't solve the issue.

Anybody can help in this?

Comment: That's correct behavior since your rule is redirecting based on `HTTP_USER_AGENT`. To prevent that redirection you can use this URL: `ttp://www.example.com/ProImages/abc.jpg?desktop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can allow access to the image folder for the mobile version

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^desktop
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android|avantgo|blackberry|iphone [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ProImages/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Well, this seems legitimate answer to my question. As this is the only folder I am concerned with, that can work beautifully. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do a symbolick link to your images folder from the Mobile folder.

If you have shell access, inside the Mobile folder do:

```
ln -s /path/to/document/root/ProImages ./ProImages
```

That way you can call for `Mobile/ProImages` and the contents being displayed are from `ProImages`from the parent folder.

Comment: Nice solution, will look at this as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

Normally I'm all for redirecting using the server but for mobile using PHP. I recommend using mobile_detect class. I works **extremely well** and it matches on just about everything. You can even detect based on specifics such as if on a tablet or an ipad or whatever you want. It's very easy to use rather than doing user agent with .htaccess. So you can do an if statement like below and then do a redirect with php.

Here is code samples for their page.
http://mobiledetect.net/

```
// Include and instantiate the class.
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

// Any mobile device (phones or tablets).
if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
  header('Location: http://m.example.com/'.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
}

// Any tablet device.
if( $detect->isTablet() ){

}

// Exclude tablets.
if( $detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet() ){

}

// Check for a specific platform with the help of the magic methods:
if( $detect->isiOS() ){

}

if( $detect->isAndroidOS() ){

}

// Alternative method is() for checking specific properties.
// WARNING: this method is in BETA, some keyword properties will change in the future.
$detect->is('Chrome')
$detect->is('iOS')
$detect->is('UC Browser')
// [...]

// Batch mode using setUserAgent():
$userAgents = array(
'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; Desire HD Build/IMM76D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19',
'BlackBerry7100i/4.1.0 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 VendorID/103',
// [...]
);
foreach($userAgents as $userAgent){

  $detect->setUserAgent($userAgent);
  $isMobile = $detect->isMobile();
  $isTablet = $detect->isTablet();
  // Use the force however you want.

}

// Get the version() of components.
// WARNING: this method is in BETA, some keyword properties will change in the future.
$detect->version('iPad'); // 4.3 (float)
$detect->version('iPhone') // 3.1 (float)
$detect->version('Android'); // 2.1 (float)
$detect->version('Opera Mini'); // 5.0 (float)
// [...]
```

Comment: missing an apostrophe at the end of  `header('Location: http://m.example.com/'.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].');`

Comment: @Lupin Oops yes I wrote it fast. :) fixed.

Comment: I was previously using this, but htaceess way was much better. Thanks for the info :)